# Quelle est la difficulté de prononciation de « séchesse » (/sɛʃɛs/) ?

Tags: phonétique

L'entrée anglaise Wiktionary pour *sécheresse* comporte une entrée ["Étymologie"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%C3%A9cheresse#Etymology) (non présente dans la version française) :

> Etymology
>   *sèche*, feminine of *sec* +‎ *-esse*. The medial -*er*- probably developed because of the difficulty of pronouncing *séchesse* (/sɛʃɛs/).

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi il serait difficile de prononcer la syllabe /ʃɛs/  ? Si c'est vrai, cette difficulté n'impacte pas le mot [manchestérien](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/manchest%C3%A9rien) (\mɑ̃.ʃɛs.te.ʁjɛ̃) ou [d'autres mots](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%CA%83%C9%9Bs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=wLZ6V-mpFqTQjwTqrIVA#q=%22%CA%83%C9%9Bs%22&start=0) dans d'autres langues.

Comment: Je pense que ce n'est pas /ʃɛs/, qui n'a rien de difficile, mais /s_ʃ_s/ où les _ sont des voyelles. Je crois qu'on ne trouve pas /s_ʃ_s/ en français.

Comment: On retrouve la même difficulté de prononciation dans "Un chasseur sachant chasser" ou dans "les chaussettes de l'archiduchesse". Des séries de consonnes sibilantes (s, z, j et ch) dans des syllabes consécutives donnent lieu à énormément d'erreurs de production ("Chèchèche"). Ceci dit, sécheresse (que j'ai honnêtement un peu de mal à prononcer dans l'état) pourrait tout simplement avoir l'infinitif comme base.

Comment: Je prendrais cette étymologie avec une précaution puisqu'il n'y a pas vraiment de source reliée qui puisse confirmer ces dires, considérant que le Wiktionnaire est le projet frère de l'encyclopédie où tous peuvent écrire.

Comment: @Archa *Séchesse* (et ses variantes *séchece, séchesce, secchece et seichece*) sont attestées en ancien francais. http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/sechece

Comment: Je me demande si l'auteur de la question voulait savoir un peu pourquoi c'est devenu *sécheresse*.

Comment: Ca me refait penser à la fameuse phrase "Les chaussettes de l'archiduchesse sont sèches et archi-sèches" : Celui qui prononce cette phrase, avec des /s/ et des /ʃ/ à la chaîne a tendance à les mélanger, et comprend la difficulté à ne pas mélanger les consonnes de séchesse.

Comment: @Gilles: Après courte étude, on a des surchaussures, des sous-chaussettes, ça arrive régulièrement entre les mots ("ce schiste" / "sa chanson" / ~"ses choses"), et c'est tout ce que j'ai trouvé. Ton commentaire semble être la meilleure réponse à la question.

Answer (score 2):

En ancien français, on trouve en concurrence au moins trois synonymes du **sécheresse** actuel ***séchesse*** (c.f. richesse), ***sécheur*** (c.f. moiteur, puanteur) et ***sècheté*** (c.f. dureté, pureté, humidité).

On peut supposer que ***sécheur*** a perdu son sens de « ce qui est sec »  pour se spécialiser plus tard dans celui de « celui qui sèche ».

Aucun mot français contemporain ne paraissant contenir la suite [**s**]+voyelle+[**ʃ**]+voyelle+[**s**], on peut donc admettre, mais ce n'est qu'un hypothèse, que ***séchesse*** a fini par évoluer en **sécheresse** à cause de cette suite de deux sifflantes sourdes séparées par une chuintante sourde, source connue de difficulté de prononciation en français, comme les commentaires sur **les chaussettes de l'archiduchesse** et le **chasseur sachant chasser** nous le rappellent, et aussi **six chiens chassent six chats**.

On peut d’ailleurs constater qu'il existe bien d'autres mot en /**-əʁɛs**/ comme **chasseresse**, **pécheresse**, **vengeresse**, **forteresse**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Phonétiquement parlant, sans s'aventurer dans l'étymologie, je dirais simplement que la difficulté de prononciation de ce type de mot est un peu similaire au [vire-langue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virelangue) bien connu

> Le chasseur sachant chasser sans son chien ni sa chaussette...